# Displaying Base64 image

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have images stored as Base64, but I'm having trouble displaying them. I'm using ASP.NET, and here is part of the code:

```
int visitorId = int.Parse(Request.QueryString["id"]);
classes.Visitor visitor = new classes.Visitor(visitorId, PageExtension_CurrentUser.Community.Id);

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append("<table>");
sb.Append(@"<tr><td colspan=""2""><div style=""width:320px; height:240px; border: 1px dotted #000;"">");

if (visitor.VisitorImage != "")
{
    sb.Append(@"<img style=""width:320px; height:240px;"" alt="" src=""data:image/jpeg;base64, " + visitor.VisitorImage + @""" />");
}
else
{
    sb.Append(@"No image");
}

sb.Append("</div></td></tr>");

sb.Append("<tr><td style='width:200px;'><b>Visitor Name</b></td><td>" + visitor.GetFullname() + "</td></tr>");
sb.Append("<tr><td><b>Company/Address</b></td><td>" + visitor.AddressOrCompany + "</td></tr>");
```

Interesting to note, is that:

1. the DIV with dotted border displayed, however no image is shown.
2. The remaining  are not printed out??
3. The image data is fine, I have already tested it on http://base64online.org/decode/ and i see the image im using for testing.

I am assuming it is the data, but why is it not shown? Any ideas?

Comment: Add double quotes also here `alt="""" ` View the source code to see whats is render

Answer (score 0):

This line of code is wrong:

```
sb.Append(@"<img style=""width:320px; height:240px;"" alt="" src=""data:image/jpeg;base64, " + visitor.VisitorImage + @""" />");
```

It should be:

```
sb.Append(@"<img style=""width:320px; height:240px;"" alt="""" src=""data:image/jpeg;base64, " + visitor.VisitorImage + @""" />");
```